# Erro:Foi tentada uma operação em algum item que não é um soquete!

Tags: python, socket

Estava tentando fazer um scanner de portas bem simples,mas quando ele achava uma porta aberta, os erros que apareciam mudavam de **[WinError 10061] Nenhuma conexão pôde ser feita porque a máquina de destino as recusou ativamente** *(q era o esperado)* para **[WinError 10038] Foi tentada uma operação em algum item que não é um soquete!**

```
def ScanPorts(host,Range):
i=1
while i <= int(Range):
    try:
        s.connect((host , i))
        print(i)
        lista_portas.append(i)
        s.close()
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
    except Exception as e :
        print(str(i) + ":" + str(e))
    i=i+1
for i in lista_portas:
    print('Porta:',i,"aberta")
```

Comment: Estás a usar python 3?

Answer (score 1):

Deves refazer/criar outra a socket para uma conecção diferente, também ajustei um bocado o código com base no que colocaste:

```
import socket

host = 'google.com'
rg = range(70, 100)
open_ports = []
def ScanPorts(host,rg):
    for i in rg:
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.settimeout(1)
            s.connect((host,i))
            print('Success with port', i)
        except Exception as err:
            print('port closed', i)
        else:
            open_ports.append(str(i))
    return open_ports

open_ports = ScanPorts(host, rg)
print('Portas ABertas:\n{}'.format('\n'.join(open_ports)))
```